# Installing 32-bit Ruby on 64-bit OS

Tags: ruby, x86, 64-bit, passenger

As far as I know, when we run Ruby applications on 64-bit Ruby, it consumes more memory than 32-bit Ruby, this is due to pointer address-space.

My machine has 64GB RAM, so in order to access the full 64GB of memory, I installed a 64-bit OS.

1. Is it possible to install a 32-bit Ruby on 64-bit OS?
2. By installing a 32-bit Ruby on 64-bit OS, will my 32-bit Ruby be able to use 64 GB RAM?
3. What are the pros and cons of running 32-bit Ruby on a 64-bit OS?

I had noticed that running my Ruby on Rails application on 64-bit Ruby consumes more RAM than 32-bit Ruby. I am using Phusion Passenger so it forks or creates new Ruby processes for each request, so each individual Ruby process (user request) is limited to 2 GB in 32-bit Ruby or the overall Ruby process is limited to access only 2GB in 32-bit Ruby.

---

My Rails application codebase is large and I plan to replicate the same code as multiple Rails applications for multiple clients in a single server so every MB of RAM is important for me, so if more RAM is free I can run additional applications for additional clients.

For more information about the application architecture see "[(Using phusion passenger + Nginx) running same rails app with multiple instance names with same port (80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272776/using-phusion-passenger-nginx-running-same-rails-app-with-multiple-instance)".

Comment: This is much-ado-about-nothing. Most Rails apps run 50 - 150MB per instance, so you'll exhaust your CPU scheduling sooner than the RAM.

Comment: @RobertK  My Rails application code base is large and i plan to replicate the same code as multiple rails applications for multiple clients in single server so every MB of RAM is important for me, so if more RAM is free i can run additional application for additional client

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to install a 32-bit Ruby on 64-bit OS?

1. Yes, it is possible.

   ---

> By installing a 32-bit Ruby on 64-bit OS, will my 32-bit Ruby be able to use 64 GB RAM?

2. No, it can't access 64 GB RAM. 32-bit processes are limited to 2 GB by default, 3 max if marked LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE, but not more.

   ---

> What are the pros and cons of running 32-bit Ruby on a 64-bit OS?

3. Cons: You're limited to 2 GB of memory.

   ---

You're worrying about nothing, though. The pointer sizes going from 32-bit (4 bytes) to 64-bits (8 bytes) only affects the pointers. If you have 64 GB of RAM and a 64-bit processor that can use them, use the 64-bit version.

Comment: I had noticed while, running my ruby on rails application on 64 bit ruby consumes more RAM than 32 bit ruby and I am using phusion passenger so it forks or create new ruby process for each request , so each individual ruby process (ie. user request) is limited to 2 GB in 32 bit ruby or over all ruby process is limited to access only 2GB in 32 bit ruby.

Comment: You're assuming Windows.  On x86-64 Linux, 32-bit processes under a 64-bit kernel can use all but a couple pages of the 4GiB of virtual address space.  (But the i386 System V calling convention is less efficient than some 32-bit calling conventions used under Windows; 32-bit binaries on Linux are mostly for backwards compat except maybe for code with pointer-heavy data structures where 32-bit pointers saves cache footprint and memory bandwidth.)

Answer (score 2):

> ...I plan to replicate the same code as multiple Rails applications for multiple clients in a single server so every MB of RAM is important for me...

Don't write monolithic applications, write smaller Rails apps that call central code that handles as much processing as possible for all apps calling it. It'd be a tiny bit slower, but much more efficient memory-wise.

Look into something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) as the backend. It's amazingly efficient and great for this sort of task. The [AMQP](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp/) gem is your friend.

Throw your data around the queues using JSON. It makes it easy to debug.

Comment: I have updated my post with application architecture, can you please check it out

Comment: You say your code base is "large", but that tells us nothing. A large number of lines? Requires a large amount of RAM for processing? Quote hard facts so there is something useful to work with. If you are using a lot of RAM, figure out how to share code, which is what a MQ is for and store data in fast DB tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, note: the discussion is between 32 bit ruby and 64 bit ruby

Comment: The discussion is "My Rails application code base is large and i plan to replicate the same code as multiple rails applications for multiple clients in single server so every MB of RAM is important for me, so if more RAM is free i can run additional application for additional client" Write your system right and you can fit in a huge amount of processing. I can't say more, but you'd be surprised what we squeeze into tiny VMs this way.

Comment: @theTinMan Prescribing the OP to use message queues and Service Oriented Architecture is completely irrelevant to the question at hand. The question is about computing architecture and address space sizes.

Comment: The question is also about "...I plan to replicate the same code as multiple Rails applications for multiple clients in a single server so every MB of RAM is important for me...".